# Unable to connect to DB with instance and port number

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, mono

My C# program is trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 from mono (V4.8.0) environment using connection string provided by a 3rd party library. In that, the server name is mentioned in the form of hostname\instance,port. Eg: "Server=192.168.1.120\db2008,5213;Database=DB_MACHINE;Connection Timeout=10;Application Name=192.168.1.13;User ID=hubuser;Password=password"

In the [Mono website](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlclient/), it is mentioned that database server name can be mentioned in these three ways, hostname or hostname,port or hostname\instance.

Because I receive the connection string from 3rd party library, there is very very less chance to change it. Is there any way in Mono to accept connection string with server name of form hostname\instance,port? If it is already supporting, I kindly request folks to help with details on how to debug this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. As mentioned in the mono website, the data source in connection string has to in mentioned format. If instance name is provide along with port number, the hostname along with instance name is assigned as server name and the connection fails. Below is the piece of code from private bool ParseDataSource (string theDataSource, out int thePort, out string theServerName) in mono-mono-4.8.0-branch\mcs\class\System.Data\System.Data.SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs file.

```
int idx = 0;
if ((idx = theDataSource.IndexOf (',')) > -1) {
    theServerName = theDataSource.Substring (0, idx);
    string p = theDataSource.Substring (idx + 1);
    thePort = Int32.Parse (p);
} else if ((idx = theDataSource.IndexOf ('\\')) > -1) {
    theServerName = theDataSource.Substring (0, idx);
    theInstanceName = theDataSource.Substring (idx + 1);

    // do port discovery via UDP port 1434
    port = DiscoverTcpPortViaSqlMonitor (theServerName, theInstanceName);
    if (port == -1)
        success = false;
} else
    theServerName = theDataSource;
```

I'm not sure if this is the expected protocol or if not, whether Mono source code would be updated or not. Submitted the information on Git.